# Landing page nav-link redirecting not scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I built a fully functional landing page with html and javascript.  I am currently trying to integrate the landing into a larger angularjs application as a component.  I have got everything to work by dynamically adding all my css and js files to all the components.  The only issue I have is that a navbar at the top of the page when clicked doesn't scroll down like it should be is instead trying to redirect the application to a non-existent page/component.

What happens is the landing page is at

```
localhost:4200/landing
```

With the following in the html

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#top-of-page">
      <img src="" width="1" height="1" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="" style="margin-right: 6px">Home
    </a> <!--img width and height used to be 30x30 px -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      Menu
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#download">Download</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-signup" style="margin-left: 15px;">Sign Up</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-login">Log In</button>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

When I click on "About" for example instead of scrolling to the about section the application redirects to

```
localhost:4200/#about
```

I have a js file with the first function with // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing commented above it is not being called for some reason.

```
(function($) {
  "use strict"; // Start of use strict

  // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
  $('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    console.log("darrel");
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 48)
        }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  // var crapStick = function() {
  //   console.log("Pam");
  // };

  // Closes responsive menu when a scroll trigger link is clicked
  $('.js-scroll-trigger').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
  });

  // Activate scrollspy to add active class to navbar items on scroll
  $('body').scrollspy({
    target: '#mainNav',
    offset: 54
  });

  // Collapse Navbar
  var navbarCollapse = function() {
    if ($("#mainNav")[0] != undefined) {
    if ($("#mainNav").offset().top > 100) {
      $("#mainNav").addClass("navbar-shrink");
    } else {
      $("#mainNav").removeClass("navbar-shrink");
    }
  }
  };
  // Collapse now if page is not at top
  navbarCollapse();
  // Collapse the navbar when page is scrolled
  $(window).scroll(navbarCollapse);

})(jQuery); // End of use strict
```

I know the file is accessible/in the right scope because navbarCollapse is being properly called.  Please feel free to ask for any extra code that could be useless in at least identifying the source of the problem.  Also I should mention all of this code is working as a stand alone landing page.

Comment: Removed my answer as it wasn't what you were looking for. **1>** All `href` with `#` is by default treated as `routing path`. So its a predictable behavior, it cant happen at random.  **2>**  I havent provided smooth scroll as it wasn't asked. You can get that "smooth scroll" code over internet and implement it as a `directive`. So try  creating a directive and if that doesn't work then share ur code. **you are mixing jquery, which is a bad practice**

Comment: You can get rid of `#` redirection by  AngularJS by adding `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');` as well.